# Symfony Easy Admin demo syntax error in core framework file

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony2-easyadmin

I was trying to configure Easy Admin demo app on my local environment. I followed the steps given in [easy admin GitHub repo](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/easy-admin-demo). However, when I am trying to access the demo app, I am getting this error.

[image]

Since I haven't touched the file mentioned in the error, I am sure that this has something to do with the dependencies of the project. I tried updating the dependencies, clearing cache etc. with no success in getting rid of the error. Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Comment: The Parse error `syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)` means that there is  php syntax error in the code, like `echo if;`. I'd check the entity class for `const`. It might be related to your PHP version as well, it might not support new syntax.